# Are we required to defend the omniscience of Hashem?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, theology

Commenting on [Bereishit 6:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.6.6?with=Rashi&lang=bi&aliyot=0), Rashi provides examples for defending the Omniscience of HaShem by stating: "The following extract from the Midrash Rabbah I am writing in order that you may know how to refute the arguments of certain heretics"

> A gentile once asked Rabbi Joshua, the son of Korcha, saying to him, “Do you not admit that the Holy One, blessed be He, knows what is to happen in the future?” He replied, “Yes.” The gentile retorted, “But is it not written ‘and He was grieved in His heart’?” He answered: “Have you ever had a son born to you?” The reply was “Yes.” He asked (the gentile): “And what did you do?” He replied: “I rejoiced and I made others rejoice also.” The Rabbi asked him: “But did you not know that he must die?” The heathen replied: “At the time of joy, let there be joy, at the time of mourning let there be mourning”. The Rabbi then said: “Such, too, is the way of the Holy One, blessed be He: although it was clear to Him that in the end men would sin and would be destroyed, He did not refrain from creating them for the sake of the righteous men who were to issue from them” (Genesis Rabbah 27:4).

Based on Rashi's example, **are we required to defend the Omniscience of HaShem?**

Comment: I don't understand the question. The gemara also tells a story where Rabbi Gamliel once went on a boat. **Are we required to go on boats?**

Comment: @Double AA - The bouyancy of this question does not cause it to float above literal-minded thinkers, a boat is not required to see this question at surface-level. * Would defending the omniscience of Eloheinu be required based on HaTorah or Halakhah?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, although it would be good to do so. I say this because Ralbag felt that G-d does not know the future. ibn Ezra wrote that G-d only knows generalities but not the details. Rambam might have felt this way also, but he writes elsewhere that G-d did not "test" Abraham because G-d would already know the outcome.

Comment: Do you have sources for these claims?

Comment: @Alex ibn Ezra writes in his commentary to Genesis 18:21: “for it is the truth that the All (namely, G-d) knows every particular (only) in a general manner, but not in a detailed manner.”